# 90's graphic novel, contains elves addicted to magic/dreaming

Tags: story-identification, comics, elves

I've for some time now been trying to track down a graphic novel published most likely in the 90's as I read it in the mid to late nighties in my school library.

From what I remember, the main character was a grumpy half-elf character who wore all black, *Three Musketeers*-style boots, a big cloak and a large hat much like a witch hunter and was armed with a crossbow. He had a stealthy-assail-type vibe.

There was also a female queen character who wore armour I think he assisted, reminiscent of Joan of Arc. There was a scene where she is addressing a crowd of townsfolk, someone throws an egg at her, she catches it and crushes it. I think she had black hair and large plated armour on her shoulders.

There were also elves in the world that the bounty hunter visited in a woodland setting; they sniffed from cauldrons and were seemingly addicted to magic or "the dreaming", as they called it.

The art work style was painted, not too dissimilar to Simon Davis's style from Slaine, if anything, maybe a little more painterly and less hyper real.

Stylistically the magical world was reminiscent in it's portrayal of peasants and gentry a little like Revolution-era France.

I read the book in the UK. It was relatively slim around A4 in size and probably a part of a larger series of graphic novels.

Comment: I started thinking it might be Drew Hayes' *Poison Elves*, but AFAIR, only the covers were painted.

Comment: Dagnabbit, missed the "graphic novel" mention.  The *Borderland* books were never made into graphic novels, AFAIK...

Comment: thanks for the suggestions all, I checked Poison Elves and Borderland books, not them, it's definitely a graphic novel with full colour painted art and the magic world is reminiscent of revolutionary era france (18th century) but it contains elves and magic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "*Legends of Larian*" series by Jeff Anderson and Terry Murray?
Book 1 - The Shadow's Edge
Book 2 - The Cutting Edge

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think these might be the correct books, specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't.

Comment: I remember reading these books at my primary/elementary school in the late 90s myself. The cover of Book 2 (The Cutting Edge) features whom I believe to be the half(?)-elf bounty hunter; his grumpy demeanor seems to be a natural byproduct of how the setting treats elves -- or at least the town he's in. Saves a human stable boy from being beaten, only to have said kid call him a freak and run off while declaring their intent to join the elf(?)-hunters. Can't remember whether or not the elf loosed a bolt into their spine in retribution... Does that sound familiar?

Comment: That's it! I remember that scene too with the helping of the stable boy and the freak comment! That is fantastic these are definitely the books. I can't wait to order a copy. Were you reading this in the UK or elsewhere?  couldn't find a wiff of it in the UK. I can't wait to revist it. thanks so much.

Comment: Ordered a copy of book 1 and 2, I think that was the run, can't seem to find any others. It was illustrated by an artist whoworked on judge dredd, I can now definitely see the connection.

Comment: Imma buy a set meself as well, just for nostalgia's sake. Only came across your stackexchange question because I was trying to remember the name of the book/series; ended up searching for the word "EDGE" (the only word I could recall) and trawling through the entire 90s catalogue before I found a familiar looking cover picture. Glad I was of some help, albeit four years late.

Comment: And this was when I was in New Zealand for a bit, could barely comprehend a lick of English at the time.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to refer to a series of short story collections edited by Terri Windling (and Mark Alan Arnold on the first two): *Borderland*, *Bordertown*, and *Life on the Border*, which also spawned three spinoff novels.

The core premise was that, in some modern time (1990s?), the Elflands had returned to contact with the human world.  Magic didn't work (more than very sporadically) in our world, technology wasn't something to bet your life on in the Elflands, but on the border, both were usable (and neither reliable).  The result, after a few years of adjustment time, was that Bordertown became a destination for runaway youth, a haven for offbeat music and magic.  Elves, humans, and hybrids mixed (in some areas; others were racist, with the shape of the ears more important than the color of the skin).

The details in the question seem to be a mix of one story from *Borderland* (the elf queen and the cauldron) and another from *Bordertown* (the large halfie with the crossbow).